# Streaming data from a bluetooth Android device into Unity3D

Tags: java-native-interface, unity-game-engine

I am able to stream data into an Android App using Java and the Android Development Kit tools.  I've started a project in Unity where I want to take that same stream of data and react to the values of the data within a Unity scene.  The only solution that I've found is to create a Unity plugin: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html

However, using a plugin is quite slow.  I was wondering if there was another solution to stream data via bluetooth into a Unity scene on an Android device.